# Yii2 site/page 404 error

Tags: yii2, url-routing, yii2-advanced-app

After a couple of weeks break for other commitments, I came back to my Yii2 work, ran `composer update` on my current projects, & am getting 404 errors on any previously working pages in `@frontend/views/site/pages`.

My URL manager is...

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'suffix' => '.p2m', // confuses bad guys
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<view:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/'=>'site/page',
    ]
],
```

An example of the line from my Navbar is...

```
['label' => 'Some Page', 'url' => ['/site/page', 'view' => 'somepage']],
```

Producing the URL...

```
http://example.com/site/page.p2m?view=somepage
```

Prior to today this all worked, & I'm tearing my hair out trying to makes sense of why it no longer does.

TIA, Pedro

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've confused the names of the action?

Please show your actionPage() in SiteController. May be you have actionPage**s**() instead?

Also you can beautify your code.

```
actionPage($view)
```

Then add in rules

```
'site/page/<view:[\w-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

And Url site/page/somepage will work.

But better way is make PageController and every page as separate action.

Also check your .htaccess and httpd.conf (if using apache) or nginx config to make sure that the server is working correctly.